# Why can't I get the tag name of xml file from curl_exec from twitter query?

Tags: javascript, dom, namespaces

I am using the twitter search API namely:

```
$search = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=" . $q . "";

$tw = curl_init();

curl_setopt($tw, CURLOPT_URL, $search);
curl_setopt($tw, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$twi = curl_exec($tw);
```

$tw seems like a legit .xml file. I output it to a file and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns:google="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:twitter="http://api.twitter.com/">
  <id>tag:search.twitter.com,2005:search/&quot;japan&quot;</id>
  <link type="text/html" href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%22japan%22" rel="alternate"/>
  <link type="application/atom+xml" href="http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%22japan%22" rel="self"/>
  <title>&quot;japan&quot; - Twitter Search</title>
  <link type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="http://search.twitter.com/opensearch.xml" rel="search"/>
  <link type="application/atom+xml" href="http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%22japan%22&amp;since_id=53215162768965632" rel="refresh"/>
  <twitter:warning>since_id removed for pagination.</twitter:warning>
  <updated>2011-03-30T22:00:58Z</updated>
  <openSearch:itemsPerPage>15</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
  <link type="application/atom+xml" href="http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?max_id=53215162768965632&amp;page=2&amp;q=%22japan%22" rel="next"/>
  <entry>
    <id>tag:search.twitter.com,2005:53215162768965632</id>
    <published>2011-03-30T22:00:58Z</published>
    <link type="text/html" href="http://twitter.com/kobe_nowplaying/statuses/53215162768965632" rel="alternate"/>
    <title>#NowPlaying &quot;Deora Ar Mo Chroi&quot; by Enya on album &quot;A Day Without Rain (Japan)&quot;</title>
    <content type="html">&lt;a href=&quot;http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23NowPlaying&quot; onclick=&quot;pageTracker._setCustomVar(2, 'result_type', 'recent', 3);pageTracker._trackPageview('/intra/hashtag/#NowPlaying');&quot;&gt;#NowPlaying&lt;/a&gt; &amp;quot;Deora Ar Mo Chroi&amp;quot; by Enya on album &amp;quot;A Day Without Rain (&lt;b&gt;Japan&lt;/b&gt;)&amp;quot;</content>
    <updated>2011-03-30T22:00:58Z</updated>
    <link type="image/png" href="http://a1.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png" rel="image"/>
    <twitter:geo>
    </twitter:geo>
    <twitter:metadata>
      <twitter:result_type>recent</twitter:result_type>
    </twitter:metadata>
    <twitter:source>&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.h-fj.com/blog/&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;TWTunes&lt;/a&gt;</twitter:source>
    <twitter:lang>en</twitter:lang>
    <author>
      <name>kobe_nowplaying (kobe_nowplaying)</name>
      <uri>http://twitter.com/kobe_nowplaying</uri>
    </author>
  </entry>
```

When I try to use AJAX and get a responseXML back and search for tags using getElementsByTagName("entry") it returns a 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null"

The HTML Code:

```
<button onclick="getTweet('tweetOut.xml')">Get Tweets!</button>
```

The JS code:

```
...
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
    x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("entry");
}
...
```

The program always hangs at that JS line. Any ideas? i tried using a much simpler XML file and my code seems to be fine. Is there something different with the output from curl_exec?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you parse XML using PHP and echo output via AJAX?

Comment: @webarto: I think in the original code, that is how the author does it but I encountered some other errors and so I wanted to start from the basics. The tutorial I am using is from here: http://papermashup.com/using-the-twitter-search-api/ and in there, he creates a new SimpleXMLElement, then some preg_replace, then some strip tags and did a foreach loop but I encountered errors and since I cannot debug that php file, i prefer to just output the XML and parse the results. I can debug the JS file using web inspector.

Comment: Ok, I copied my script, so you can see basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$search = "webarto";

$feed = curl("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=$search");

$tags = array("title", "name", "uri", "published");
foreach($tags as $tag){
    $atom["$tag"] = matchTags("$tag", $feed);
}
unset($atom["title"][0]);
$atom["title"] = array_values($atom["title"]);

for($i = 0; $i < count($atom["title"]); $i++){
    $atom["title"][$i] = htmlentities($atom["title"][$i], ENT_QUOTES);
    $atom["title"][$i] = preg_replace("/http\:\/\/(.*?)\s/",'<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://\\1">http://\\1</a> ',$atom["title"][$i]);
    $atom["published"][$i] = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($atom["published"][$i]));
    echo('<li><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="'.$atom["uri"][$i].'">'.$atom["title"][$i].' ('.$atom["published"][$i].')</a></li>');
}

function matchTags($tag, $xml){
    preg_match_all("#\<$tag\>(.*?)\<\/$tag\>#is", $xml, $bingo);
    return $bingo[1];
}
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Result (rendered HTML)...

```
# test #stackoverflow (01.04.2011)
```

Comment: Thank you. I found out that my XML file was corrupted. I tried your code and it works also so thank you. But, when it is Japanese chars, the output does not come out to be jap chars instead as &123, etc...

Comment: Yko, just replace `htmlentities($atom["title"][$i], ENT_QUOTES);` with `$atom["title"][$i];`, in `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the same XML without first row `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Or try:

```
x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("entry")[0]; //I think this will return you first entry
```

Comment: I just tried that and it still returns me error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null

Answer (score 0):

You probably should wait for the document to be loaded:
like this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=onResponse;
function onResponse() {
    x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("entry");
}
```